# How to return ID of Db saved JSON in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, response

I am building a sample app for JSON tutorial.
After posting JSON object (description and date), an ID should be auto generated in the database.
How can I get this ID as the only field in the JSON response?

```java
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @PostMapping(path = "/api/object/new")
    public Object AddObjectApi(@RequestBody Map<String, String> object) {

        Object newObject = new Object(
            object.get("description"),
            LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

        Object savedObject = repository.save(newObject);
        savedCObject.getId();

        return savedObject;
    }
```

Sample input (Post JSON):

```
{
   "description" : "This is object description"
}
```

Sample Output (Returned JSON response):

```
{
   "id" : "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class which has a field called id

```
public class ResponseData{
   public Integer id;
   
   public ResponseData(){
   
   }

   public ResponseData(Integer id){
     this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Then after saving your object in db you can return the response like this

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/api/object/new")
    public ResponseData AddObjectApi(@RequestBody Map<String, String> object) {

        Object newObject = new Object(
            object.get("description"),
            LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

        Object savedObject = repository.save(newObject);
        
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData(savedObject.getId());
        return responseData;
    }
```

Comment: returned empty JSON ( {} ). even though the object is saved in the DB

Comment: Please try removing the @JsonView Annotation and change your AddObjectApi method's return type to ResponseData and let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Entity class then `id` column in you entity should have this line

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
and when you save your Entity class in database `.save` will return the saved entity which contain the newly generated id

`entity = repository.save(entity);`
and then you can get the id of the data saved in database
`entity.getId()`

you can create another pojo class only with id vaiable with getter setter and return the instance of your pojo

```
ResponseSchema response = new ResponseSchema();
response.setId(entity.getId);

return response;
```

Comment: I am using Entity Class. Your solutions returned the response as only "id" value ( example: 1). But I need to return it as JSON object with only one field (example: {"id" : "1"}

Comment: you can create another pojo class set id and return the instance of your pojo.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english.

First of all, i'm using Jackson to convert object to json or conversely.

Create an entity wich represent ure json Object.

i'm considering that u're working with JPARepository

[YourJsonEntity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMZCF.png)

*// Start to convert ure JSON to Entity*

```
YourJsonEntity entity = new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, YourJsonEntity.class);
```

*// Persist your object*
*// **Save return the object from DataBase. He has a value ID***

```
YourJsonEntity entityFromDb = this.entityRepository.save(entity);
System.out.println(entityFromDb.getId());
```

I found this to extract properties as JSON

```
String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"FIAT\" }";
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
String color = jsonNode.get("color").asText();
// Output: color -> Black
```